# Having 2 LCD screens with one vga output of laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors

Is there a way that allows connecting 2 monitors to a laptop that only has one VGA output?

I mean I want to extend my desktop accross 3 monitors (well, one is the laptop monitor itsef).

Will something like this work (well I doubt it myself)

[image]

Please guide!

Comment: The two external monitors, they would show the same image, or different?

Comment: well different...extending the desktop I mean for more workspace

Comment: Not without a video card that supports multiple monitors/desktops